# new object in constructor from class undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-class

I'm creating a new object from a class in a constructor, and whenever it runs I get an error that operate is undefined in the method, though it is defined in the constructor. Operate itself is thoroughly tested and works great in a separate context so that's not the problem. I'm building it with Babel, *not* running it directly in Node 7.0.0

```
import Operate from "./operate"

export default class {

  constructor(Schema) {
    this.schema = Schema
    this.operate = new Operate(this.schema)
    console.log(this.operate.run) // <- Logs just fine
  }

  update(req, res) {
    console.log(this.operate.run) // <- Nada
    this.operate.run(req.body)
      .then(value => {
        res.status(200).json(value)
      })
  }
```

[image]

This feels like I'm missing something fundamental. I've heard this isn't a great pattern anyway, so please feel free to suggest a better way. Thanks so much in advance.

UPDATE: This is how update is being used. I don't suspect there's any problem here, as it has worked just fine when I had been importing controller as a function from another module, instead of a class

```
import {Router, } from "express"
import Controller from "../controller"
import User from "./user.model"

let controller = new Controller(User)
let router = new Router()

router.post("/", controller.update)

module.exports = router
```

Comment: how are you "executing" update?

Comment: It's a function passed into an express route.

Comment: the issue seems to be that `this` in the call to update is possibly undefined? try `console.log(this)` at the top of update to see what it is

Comment: in your `constructor`, try adding `this.update = this.update.bind(this)`.

Comment: perhaps that's why I've seen `this.update = this.update.bind(this);` - it makes sense now :p

Comment: Wow, that worked. I have to do that with all of the methods? There's gotta be a shortcut? If you write any of this up in an answer I'll be voting you up. ...So much help! :-)

Comment: `I have to do that with all of the methods?` - only the ones that need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from this:

```
router.post("/", controller.update)
```

to this:

```
router.post("/", controller.update.bind(controller))
```

When you pass `controller.update` it only passed a pointer to the method and any association with the `controller` object is lost.  Then, when that `update` method is called later, there is no association with the appropriate object and thus the `this` handler in the method is wrong and you get the error you were seeing.

You either force the binding of the `update` method within the object or when you pass the method elsewhere that might not be called correctly, you can use the above structure to pass a bound version of the method.

You could also modify your definition of the `update` method to permanently bind it to your object in the constructor by adding this to the constructor:

```
this.update = this.update.bind(this);
```

Comment: can you plz also take a look at this problem, thnx in advance 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/70037304/15454800