# How to assign user's role for a user using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two schemas `UserSchema` and `RoleTypeSchema` . In the `UserSchema` I added a field `UserRoleType` that `ref` the `RoleTypeSchema`. What I am trying to do is to create roleType in the `RoleTypeCollection`and then when i create a `UserObject` in the `UserCollection` I can see the `UserRoleType` field in `UserCollection`.

`The error that i am getting is after i create the role and user, when i get an error validation:`

`THE ERROR`

```
{"message":"userSchema validation failed: usersRoles: Path `usersRoles` is required."}
```

`UserSchema`

```
    //requiring the mongoose module 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// create the schema 
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    //creating the attributes/ data of the schema

    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    usersRoles: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'usersRolesSchema',
        required: true
    }

});


const userDB = mongoose.model('userSchema', userSchema);

module.exports = userDB;
```

`RoleTypeSchema`

```
 //requiring the mongoose module 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');



var usersRolesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    userRole: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

})

const userRolesModel = mongoose.model('usersRolesSchema', usersRolesSchema);

module.exports = userRolesModel;
```

`Create A User Controller`

```
 exports.createUser = (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('Post CREATE User /create-user');

    // getting the request body
    const username = req.body.username;
    const userRole = req.body.userRole;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const password2 = req.body.password2;

    // check the body request by using express validator
    req.checkBody('username', 'UserName is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('userRole', 'userRole is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'UserName is required').equals(req.body.password);
    // get the error if there are any 
    let errors = req.validationErrors();

    //validation for duplicate values
    if (errors) {

        userSchema.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
            .then(user => { //that's will give us the user and then i want to check if 

                if (user) {
                    //if there is an error so rerinder the templet
                    res.render('users/create_user.ejs', {
                        errors: errors //pass along the errors
                    }, console.log(errors));
                }

            });

    } else {
        let newUser = new userSchema({
            username: username, // first is the attribute NAME of the model , second is the name value tag in the html file
            userRole: userRole,
            password: password
        });

        bycrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            bycrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    //ERROR PAGE
                    console.log(err);
                }

                /// Hashing the password
                newUser.password = hash;

                newUser.save()
                    .then(data => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        } else {
                            req.flash('success', 'You successfully registered')
                            res.redirect('/halalMunchies/all-users');
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.status(500).send({
                            message: err.message || "Some error occured while creating a create operation"
                        });
                    });


            });
        });
    }


};
```

`Showing All Users Data, which here it should show the userType also`

```
    exports.allUsers = (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('GET CREATE USERS /all-users');


    userSchema.find().populate('usersRoles', 'userRole')
        .then(data => {
            res.render('users/users.ejs', { usersList: data });
            console.log();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })


};
```

`The creating userForm, in this form i will select the userRole and i can use req.body to that name tag so i can use it and save it like a username or password input`

```
<label> User Type: </label>

<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="roles" name="userRole">
    <option value="" selected data-default> Select Role </option>
        <% roles.forEach(function (role) {%>
        <option> <%= role.userRole %> </option>

        <%})%>

    </select>


<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your userSchema you have defined this

```
 usersRoles: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'usersRolesSchema',
    required: true
}
```

But when you create a user you do not pass in a userRoles to it.

You would need to create an new usersRolesSchema and then assign its id to the user when creating a new user

```
newUser = new userSchema({
        username: username, // first is the attribute NAME of the model , second is the name value tag in the html file
        userRole: userRoleID,
        password: password,
        userRoles: "id"
    });
```

Or you can just remove the required field from the usersRoles field in userSchema

Comment: Can y show how can I assign the id of the role to the user, and I can’t remove this field coz I need to show users’roles

Comment: @HeshamEldawy see 


newUser = new userSchema({
        username: username, // first is the attribute NAME of the model , second is the name value tag in the html file
        userRole: userRoleID,
        password: password,
        userRoles: "id"
    });

call save after

Comment: what is userRoleID refers ? and for userRoles : "id" , id here is a string value.

Comment: Well it refers to the this table you should create according to your flow

var usersRolesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    userRole: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

})

newUserRole = new userRole({
        userRole: "newRole"
    });
newUserRole.save()

newUser = new userSchema({
        username: username, // first is the attribute NAME of the model , second is the name value tag in the html file
        userRole: newUserRole._id,
        password: password,
        userRoles: "id"
    });
newUser.save()

Comment: i really appreciate your help but i got tired from trying all the solutions expect the correct one, so can you plz just add the answer that will run the code and then i will understand everything

Comment: You dont learn anything from me doing the work for you. I have literally solved the problem for you in my recent comment. You just need to use it. This is your code I have provided a solution for you based on your code. For further reading see
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Comment: if i created a usersRolesSchema  so in the creating roles page, it wouldn't make sense to have it. i want to make also the client able to create a role and in creating a user Page when he assign a role for that user, he will select from the roles that been created in that schema. So i don't need to create a new object from the UsersRolesSchema coz of that.

Comment: we are saying the same thing. You can create you userRole wherever you want it. But before you create a user you have to set that userRole._id on the new user object. if not you will keep getting the required error.